# Update method doesn't invoke movement of agent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating an agent to play a game. I used the A* algorithm to determine the path that the agent should take and I converted those grid locations into moves. Now I'm trying to get the agents to perform these moves in the update function but instead the agent just lingers

```
void Update ()
{    
    if (currentState == AIStates.Idle) 
    {
       runSearch ();                
    }
    if (currentState == AIStates.FollowingPath) 
    {
        if (move_index < this.MovesList.Count) 
        {
                if (currentMove == Player.Moves.Null) 
                {
                    currentMove = MovesList [move_index];
                    ExecuteMove (currentMove);    
                }
        }
        //is_followingpath = true;
    }
    if (currentState == AIStates.PathCompleted) 
    {
        currentState = AIStates.FollowingPath;
    }    
}
```

So I have something like that in my update method and my moves list is just a list with moves like MoveLeft, MoveRight etc. and I want the agent to perform these moves .. but instead the agent lingers ... all the methods have been tested and they work it's just the update method that is causing issues.

Comment: Try to debug your code to see where the code execution got stuck. maybe one of your `if` statements is blocking it and you need to change it.

Comment: i already did all of that

Comment: And It reached the `ExecuteMove(currentMove)`? if yes show this method itself.